# Tutorial: theano.grad() function not calculating gradient

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano

I have problem running a simple linear regression using Theano grad() function. It is a very simple example based on the following tutorial:

https://github.com/Newmu/Theano-Tutorials/blob/master/1_linear_regression.py

which I found a little too easy and wanted to add additional input variable (and therefore made weights an array of 2 variables). However, I cannot make grad() work as it does not converge and both W1 shared variable (weights matrix) and cost function stay the same.

Basically the example should take input matrix 5,2 (5 samples, each having 2 features) and create weight matrix (1,2) given the output vector (5 samples).

**EDIT: (I forgot to add updates=update in grad())**

Here is the code:

```
import numpy
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

input_data = numpy.matrix([[28, 1], [35, 2], [18, 1], [56, 2], [80, 3]])
output_data = numpy.matrix([1600, 2100, 1400, 2500, 3200])

TS = T.matrix("training-set")
E = T.matrix("expected")
W1 = theano.shared(numpy.asarray([0.,0.]))

O = T.dot(TS, W1.T)
cost = T.mean(T.sqr(E - O.T))
gradient = T.grad(cost=cost, wrt=W1)
update = [[W1, W1 - gradient * 0.05]]
train = theano.function([TS,E], cost, updates=update)

for i in range(100):
    print train(input_data, output_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, stupid mistake: I forgot to set updates=update in grad() invocation.